# Can't get form "custom" variable value with javacript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form, and I need to read the option values with javasript.
So when I have this :

```
<select class="login-input" name="Provenance" id="Provenance">
           <option value="">--- Provenance ---</option>
           <option value="N">Collection </option>
           <option value="P" data1="P">Prévente</option>
</select>
```

It works fine with :

```
document.getElementById('Provenance').value
```

But when I add a custom variable *modelcode* I don't know how to get the value :

```
<select class="login-input" name="Modeles" id="Modeles">
    <option value="">--- Code modele ---</option>
    <option value="00" modelcode="A">A</option>
    <option value="01" modelcode="B">B</option>
    <option value="03" modelcode="C">C</option>
</select>
```

I would like to read the *modelcode* value.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: are you using jquery in your project?

Comment: There's not tag jQuery and the snippet is in Vanilla JS so I doubt. (considering jQuery is obselete). @Megalf, I have described how the data attribute can be used to store values in your HTML attributes, let me know if that help. Also I would not advise to use `id` in form, instead, I would name my form and target from within the form scope, using `documents.forms[name]` accessor

Comment: I don't use Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, you can use `data-` attributes to store data into your attributes, as an example:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const select = document.getElementById('modeles')
  select.addEventListener('change', onModelChange, true)
}

function onModelChange(event) {
  if (event.target.value) {
    const { value, options } = event.target
    console.log({ 
      value, 
      ...options[options.selectedIndex].dataset
    })
  } else {
    console.log('no selection')
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="modeles" id="modeles">
    <option value="">--- Code modele ---</option>
    <option value="00" data-modelcode="A">A</option>
    <option value="01" data-modelcode="B">B</option>
    <option value="02" data-modelcode="C">C</option>
    <option value="03" data-modelcode="D">D</option>
</select>
```

This is the concept, in order to familiarize, you can read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Thanks. I must do something wrong, cause when I try to store it in a variable I get "undefined".
I wrote : element.getAttribute('modelecode')

Comment: If you use `getAttribute`, then you can do `element.getAttribute('data-modelcode')`, but I would recommend using dataset, because it was made for storing dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitri :)